# OpenID login broken on careers

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, login

I'm using MS Edge 25.10586 on Windows 10 Pro x64 build 10586.

In Firefox 43, and Internet Explorer 11.20.10586.0 on the same computer, everything works OK.

On other stack exchange sites OpenID works OK even in MS Edge.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open https://careers.stackoverflow.com/
2. In the upper-right corner, press “Log in”
3. Enter your Open ID
4. Press orange “Log in” button.

**Expected result**

Login.

**Actual result**

A mouse cursor briefly changes to hourglass, and then browser is redirected to the main page https://careers.stackoverflow.com/, no login, no error messages.

Comment: "Broken". Can you please give us more details, and maybe a screenshot showing what's happening?

Comment: @AlexWarren updated. As you see, nothing's happening, and nothing to screenshot.

Comment: @AlexWarren were you able to reproduce the problem?